# What are the advantages, disadvantages and applications of writing vectors as row matrix, column matrix and sum?

Tags: notation, vectors

I am asking about three very common ways to write a vector $\mathbf{V}$ with $x$-component $A$, $y$-component $B$ and $z$-component $C$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{V}&= A\mathbf{\hat i} + B\mathbf{\hat j} + C\mathbf{\hat k} \tag{1}  \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} A & B & C \end{bmatrix} \tag{2} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix} \tag{3} \\
\end{align}$$

What are the **advantages**, **disadvantages** and **applications** of notating a vector in manners $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$?

My goal with this question is to have a reference for myself and others that explicitly answers these questions in a single, clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a big difference between row vectors and column vectors.  That's because formally, under the hood, row vectors aren't vectors at all.  They're covectors, also called linear forms or linear functionals, and what this means is that they actually represent a linear map $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ in the same way an $n\times m$-dimensional matrix can be used to define a linear map $g: \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ (where $U$ is the vector space containing $\bf{V}$).

This map is really easy to define, in normal Euclidean space it's just the dot product, or equivalently matrix multiplication:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b & c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    e \\
    f \\
    g
\end{bmatrix} = ae + bf + cg
\end{equation*}

Note that it doesn't make sense to multiply row vectors with row vectors, or column vectors with column vectors.  If you've seen physics, this is the motivation for the Bra-Ket notation: in the expression $\langle a | b \rangle$, $\langle a |$ is a row vector and $| b \rangle$ is a column vector.  Together, $\langle a | b \rangle = \langle a |\text{ } | b \rangle$.

This might seem a little silly right now, since covectors very clearly correspond to normal vectors, but that's not always the case (for example, in the infinite-dimensional spaces studied in functional analysis).

On the other hand, the form $$a{\bf\hat{i}} + b {\bf\hat{j}} + c {\bf\hat{k}}$$ is exactly the same as $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\\ c\end{bmatrix}$$

I suppose the former notation is more succint in handwriting, but I've always found column vectors to be more illustrative -- you can easily tell the difference between vectors and scalars this way.  That said, the choice between the two is ultimately a matter of convenience.

Comment: Might you have any inclination as to why this question was down-voted? Despite its being rudimentary, I personally felt that this question met the site’s standards.

Comment: I have no idea, it seems like a perfectly acceptable question to me.  I don't think it had been downvoted when I answered.  Someone should have left some feedback instead of just downvoting in my opinion too.  That hardly seems productive.

Comment: I agree. Thank you so much :)

Comment: By the way I up-voted your answer in addition to ‘choosing’ it

Comment: I'm not the/a downvoter either, just guessing here, but perhaps it had something to do with the lack of either of you mentioning the common tuple notation, $\mathbf{V} = ( A , B , C ) = A \mathbf{\hat{i}} + B \mathbf{\hat{j}} + C \mathbf{\hat{k}}$, a variant of the first notation (with implicit, as in not explicitly named, basis vectors). (My thinking is, perhaps they were thinking of learners coming across this question and the accepted answer, and thought these lacking (tuple notation for vectors being very common in many fields), but forgot, or were too stupid, to explain their complaint.)